# Making div height 100%, inside stretched one wouldn't work

Tags: css, html, styles, height

I have 3 boxes (div-s).

main-box inside it two boxes. The first (Box1) floated to the right the other (Box2) floated to the left.

both boxes is set height to 100%, so when one of them stretched the main the other follow the same height

## What I did:

I made Box 2 stretch the main-box 4 lines. **But** box 2 still the same height, even it 100%.

### CODE

```
<!-- main box -->
<div style='border: 1px solid; padding: 5px;'>

    <!-- box 1 -->
    <div style='border: 1px solid; height: 100%; float: right;'>Box 1 Line 1</div>
    <!-- box 2 -->
    <div style='border: 1px solid; height: 100%; float: left;'>Box 2 Line1<br /> Box 2 Line2<br />Box 2 Line3<br />Box 2 Line4</div>

<!-- clear -->
<div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
```

### Simple Photo included.

http://im31.gulfup.com/Rn6H3.png

I'm still learning and this bug me out I don't know why box 1 wouldn't stretched with box 2 when I set it to 100% height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a height to the container.  Unless a height is specified on the containing element the browser cannot calculate the height using a percentage.  When the browser attempts to set box2 to 100% it cannot determine what height (parent elements height) the div should be 100% of.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 5px; height: 77px;">

    <!-- box 1 -->
    <div style="border: 1px solid; height: 100%; float: right;">Box 1 Line 1</div>
    <!-- box 2 -->
    <div style="border: 1px solid; height: 100%; float: left;">Box 2 Line1<br> Box 2 Line2<br>Box 2 Line3<br>Box 2 Line4</div>

<!-- clear -->
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/height):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pZHaY/

Comment: In other words, 100% of what? Setting a height for the parent provides a value for that 100% to use.

Comment: @Matt Coughlin 100% of the main-box. that's all. I guess I need to specified how height is the main box to get the others to stretched out. **GOT** it. :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have set Added text only to box 2 and as you have set the height to 100% which is equal to height:auto; it will take the size of the content as 100% so it doesn't stretch. Best solution is to set height as fixed ex: height: 200px; or you can add content and keep it height: 100%.